# Dynamically add Radio Button Labels - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, radio-button

Having trouble getting the a label dynamically assigned to a radio button.  all of the code is working except the innerHTML. Cannot spot why.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
        <form id="myForm">
        </form>
        <br>
        <button onclick="addRadio()">Add radio buttons!</button>

        <script>

            // This function will add a new Radio buttons to the above
            count = 0;
            function addRadio()
            {
                count++;
                //Create input type
                var myRadio = document.createElement("input");
                var myName = document.createElement("testRadio");
                var myBreak = document.createElement("br");
                var myLabel = document.createElement("label");
                var labelMessage = "Radio Button: " + count;
                var labelId = "l" + count;
                myRadio.setAttribute("type", "radio");
                myRadio.setAttribute("name", "testRadio");
                myRadio.setAttribute("value", "Radio Button: " + count);
                myLabel.setAttribute("for", labelId);               
                myRadio.setAttribute("id", labelId);
                document.getElementById('myForm').appendChild(myRadio);
                document.getElementById('myForm').appendChild(myLabel);
                document.getElementById('myForm').appendChild(myBreak);
                document.getElementById('labelId').innerHTML = 'labelMessage';  
            }
            
        </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label element might not be inserted by the next line itself. It is better to do

```
myLabel.innerHTML = 'labelMessage';
```

As you have the element already in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tiny error in the code.

Before the .innerHTML you get the element by id 'labelId' as a string.

You need to select with the labelID as a var so:

```
document.querySelector(`label[for="${labelId}"]`).innerHTML = labelMessage;
```

Comment: Thanks that fixes the error.  But doesnt add the label..  if I change     myLabel.setAttribute("id", labelId);    
//myRadio.setAttribute("id", labelId); it adds the label.  But then I wonder if the label is then properly associated with the radio button. (sorry cant figure out how to hit enter without submitting the reply)

Comment: Yeah I just realised that the id is not set on the label but on the input field. the answer by @boredfromboredom is simpler.  juste remove the innerHTML line and add his line after creating the label and the labelMessage and you're good to go.